# Scala: constrain a class type parameter for a member function

Tags: scala, types

Given a class `A` with a type parameter `T`, how can I further constrain `T` for a specific function? In the example below, I want to enforce that `foo` can only be called if `T` is an `Int` (or a subtype of, if you like). I.e. `new A[Int]().foo()` should compile, but `new A[Double]().foo()` should not compile.

I can achieve what I want with an implicit conversion `T => Int` as demonstrated in `foo`. However that results in an unnecessary method invocation - the evidence that is implicitly found is the identity function. Also, it doesn't look nice...

```
class A[T] {
  val someValue: T = ???

  def foo()(implicit ev: T => Int): Int = ev(someValue)

  // some ideas that don't quite work
  // def bar[T2 <: Int :EqualTo[T]](t2: T2): T = t2.asInstanceOf[T]
  // def bam[T2 <: T with Int](): Int = someValue.asInstanceOf[Int]

  def thisOneDefinesItsOwnConstraintType[Z <: Int](z: Z): Z = z
  def thisOneDoesNotNeedToConstrainT(t: T): T = someValue
}
```

The solution gets bonus points if it does not need to cast :)

Note: I know that I can define a type constraint either on the class or method level (see `thisOneDefinesItsOwnConstraintType`), but that doesn't help me because I also have some methods that don't need to constrain the type (see `thisOneDoesNotNeedToConstrainT`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this without implicits, because while you can put some constraint `B <: C` on a class method, your requirement that `B <: T` is difficult to generalize, because we have no idea how `C` relates to an arbitary `T`. Fortunately, Scala has a construct for this already, the `<:<` type-class. An instance of `<:<[B, T]` generated in `Predef` will provide evidence that `B <: C`.

But don't just take my word for it, here's what the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/?_ga=1.8468725.1939486482.1433104516#scala.Predef$$$less$colon$less) has to say:

> To constrain any abstract type T that's in scope in a method's argument list (not just the method's own type parameters) simply add an implicit argument of type T <:< U, where U is the required upper bound; or for lower-bounds, use: L <:< T, where L is the required lower bound.

For example:

```
class E
class F extends E
class G extends F

class A[T] {
  def constrained[B <: F](b: B)(implicit ev: B <:< T): B = b
}
```

Here, we introduce an upper-bound of `F` for type parameter `B` of the `contrained` method. But if you *also* want to guarantee that `B <: T` (without adding another type parameter), you can add the implicit `B <:< T`.

```
scala> val a = new A[E]
a: A[E] = A@5a63f509

scala> a.constrained(new E)
<console>:15: error: inferred type arguments [E] do not conform to method constrained's type parameter bounds [B <: F]
       a.constrained(new E)
         ^
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : E
 required: B
       a.constrained(new E)
                     ^

scala> a.constrained(new F)
res5: F = F@4a668b6e

scala> a.constrained(new G)
res6: G = G@4de4b452
```

Comment: perfect, in my concrete example (which does not use a value parameter) this works, without cast and additional method invocation: `def foo()(implicit ev: T <:< Int): Int = someValue`

Comment: @m-z I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer as scaladoc recommends to do it this way, not for dispute, but for clarification reasons: why does this method better than the one I proposed? Mine has a benefit of not showing `constrained` in the list of methods in quick-completion of any IDE

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
implicit class AIntOps(a: A[Int]) {
  def test(x: Int) = x
}
```

With that method test will only appear for `A[Int]` and simply not available for any other `A`

Comment: That's actually what I've done previously, but would like to get away from because I want to use less implicits. It's much nicer if you can just list all the available methods in one list, rather than having that list plus a number of implicit floating around...

Comment: Late to the party, but in reference to your comment on the accepted answer, the accepted answer is more complete, it references documentation, and shows concrete example usage through the REPL (i.e. "this works, this is what I did").